# Restore contents of a previously connected USB Stick (without the USB Stick)

Tags: usb, usb-flash-drive, data-recovery, info

I forgot my USB Stick with important information in another state. So I don't have the stick with me. How can I find the content of the previously connected stick, do you think the computer has parts of it in SSD or RAM. Please help.

I searched what exactly happened when you connect a USB Flash Drive to a computer:
[What *exactly* happens when I insert my USB into a computer?](https://superuser.com/questions/708945/what-exactly-happens-when-i-insert-my-usb-into-a-computer)
And also how I could search the RAM as files. But I am no expert on this topic.

Probably I am wanting too much from a computer and there isn't a way but I wanted to ask this here because you never know.

My environment is:
MacBook Air (13-inch, Mid 2012), MacOS Catalina 10.15.7

Comment: No; The files were stored on the flash drive; Unless you copied the files they only existed on your flash drive.

Comment: OK, it wasn't likely anyways.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to set up backup software to automatically back up every external device connected. You might need complicated scripting to detect external devices and perform the backup. That would only snapshot what the drive had when it was connected. How would you run the backup again every time a new file is added?

You would need a backup folder that has a backup location named after each device ID.

This would also mean that you can't disconnect a USB drive until the backup is completed.

So you could make your computer do this but it would be a terrible waste of space and time. It's better to just keep the files you need locally on the computer in a way that you can find them.